# Finding permutation $a$ given $b$ and conjugate $a^b$

Tags: number-theory, permutations

Normally we define a conjugate relationship as

$$a^b = b~a~b^{-1}$$

But I don't know how to find $a$ given that we know $b$ and $a^b$.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f_b(a) = a^b = bab^{-1}$. What is the inverse function of this? If we apply the inverse of $f_b$ to $a^b$, we will get $a$.

**HINT:** $f_x(f_y(a))=f_{xy}(a)=xya(xy)^{-1}$. (For what $x$ is $xb$ the identity?)

Comment: Sorry my brain doesn't work like that very well. The inverse of a^b? I assume that means b^-1 a b

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean; try computing $b^{-1}a^b b$, though.

Comment: Oh I am an idiot. Thanks